# Is a c# WebService with nullabele int BasicProfile 1.1 conform

Tags: c#, web-services, nullable, standards-compliance

I want to implement a WebService that should be BasicProfile 1.1 conform.
The WebMethod should be something like this:

```
byte[] Test(int? count)
```

Is this call BasicProfile 1.1 conform?
How can I check BasicProfile 1.1 conformability?

Comment: I don't remember details but you should be able to specify WS_1_1 with an attribute. And I think you will get an error for non-conforming members.